# Can't find a route for 'post: upload/edit'. on codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Can't find a route for 'post: upload/edit'.

```
// in Routes.php

$routes->get('upload', 'UploadController::index');
$routes->add('upload', 'UploadController::create');
$routes->add('upload/edit/(:segment)', 'UploadController::edit/$1');

// in upload/index.php

<form action="<?= base_url('upload/edit/'.user()->userid) ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Maybe it works if you add it by the route type like this, $routes->post('upload/edit/(:segment)

Comment: actually, it was true, there is no `upload/edit`. Add `id` to it. example `upload/edit/1`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your Routes.php. It works for me.

```php
// Routes.php

$routes->post('upload/edit/(:any)', [UploadController::class, 'edit/$1']);
```